# How to change initial state of base parameter from sub class

Tags: c#, subclass, base-class

I'm building an application which runs "tasks". All tasks inherrit `BaseTask` which contains some default logic/functions which should be available for all tasks like `Start`, `Stop`, `Enable` and `Disable` functions.

The base class also should contain some `active` property which tells if the task is active as only "active" tasks can be started.

To give an idea about the code:

```
// As i have no idea how to declare the active param to make it work, i describe this with a comment in my code.

public abstract class BaseJob {
  private Status jobStatus;
  // some active property defined here which is false by default

  public BaseJob() {
    jobStatus = active ? Status.initialized : Status.inactive;
  }
  
  public void Start() {
    if (active) {
      Run();
    }
  }

  public void Stop() {
    if (jobStatus == Status.running) {
      // logic to stop the job
    }
  }

  public void Enable() {
    // set "active" to true
    jobStatus.initialized
  }

  public void Disable() {
    Stop();
    // Set "active" to false
    jobStatus = Status.inactive
  }

  public void Run() {
    ..
    task();
    ..
    jobStatus = Status.running;
  } 

  public abstract void task() { }
}
```

```
public class JobA: BaseJob {
  public override void task() {
    // The logic of the specific job
  }
}
```

Now the questions:

- How to define the active property in the `BaseJob` which is false by default but in such a way i can "override" its default value in a child class. Take into account:

  - That I want to change the active value with the `BaseJob` functions `Enable` and `Disable`
  - That I want to guarantee that the `active` propert can only be changed by using the related `BaseJob` functions as they may contain more logic than just toggle the "active" bool.

I already tried different ways but in eighter case i run into another issue.

- `private bool active` in the BaseJob does not work as its not accessible and overrideable (is this a correct work? :'-D ) from the child class.
- Using an abstract getter/setter cannot do the job as it cannot contain a default value in the BaseJob class
- protected getter and setter or bool is not working as i have no idea how to override the default value from the child class.
- `protected virual bool active` in the `BaseJob` is not working. `The modifier "virtual" is not valid for this item" is the error i receive.

Possible solution i see:
Probably i need to override the constructor which sets the default value isn't it? I actually want to avoid this but i think this is the only option?

Comment: sounds like you haven't tried `protected virtual bool active` in base class yet. Also, please post real and not pseudo code. especially the definition of your `BaseJob` class. Is it abstract? and if not, what would be the use case of instantiating a `BaseJob` object?

Comment: @MongZhu The `BaseJob` is `abstract` indeed. I updated my post. I just tried `protected virual bool active`  which is not working. `The modifier "virtual" is not valid for this item" is the error i get.  -- About the pseudo/real code thing, i think my pseudo code is close to my real code i just didn't add the logic and some properties to make it more clear/clean as they are not relavant to the question.

Comment: "my pseudo code is close to my real code i just didn't add the logic and some properties" that is fine, but we need to see the real code like `public abstract class...` and so on to verify your options and to asses what you might have done wrong

Comment: Show us your ACTUAL code, and please make sure it is a [mre].

Comment: Also, please restrict posts to containing a single question.

Comment: And finally, if you need to override how a property behaves, you need to use a property, not a field. I think that is why you get the error about virtual not being allowed. For example https://dotnetfiddle.net/Jbp63g

Comment: better, but still missing for example the declaration of `active` is it a field? then you cannot make it virtual, it need to be a property. I am wildly guessing here like a wanderer in a dark room...

Comment: @DavidG I updated my question so it only contains a single question. I changed the code so it represents my real code. A "minimal reproducible example" is a bit complicated when i ask for a way how to implement something...

Comment: @MongZhu I updated my question so it represents my real code ;-)

Comment: ok mate, still : `//some active property defined here` but no active **property** declared in the code.... if it would be a property you would not get an error message when trying my suggestion from the first comment. Ok I understand that you don't really know how to implement the active variable, but 1 implementation leads to a *certain* error. If you show us this implementation detail and the error we are much more able to help you. This holds for every asking person. :) We have to guess less and you have much faster a working solution. Just for future reference ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just define a protected virtual property to represent the initial active state. The active field is private so that only the base class has the possibility changing it.

```
public abstract class BaseJob
{
    private bool _active;

    protected virtual bool IsActiveByDefault => false;

    public BaseJob()
    {
        _active = IsActiveByDefault;
    }
}
```

Child classes can override the property to change the default state without touching the private active field.

```
public class JobA: BaseJob
{
    protected override bool IsActiveByDefault => true;
}
```

Comment: @CodeNinja We were trying to get you to ask a good question, that is why we commented. There's no need to get salty.

Comment: This seems like a really complicated way of just setting a value in a constructor. For example https://dotnetfiddle.net/QGE93s

Comment: @DavidG (Part 1) i think you did not understand my question (or just focus to much on how i asked my question). Shingo exactly solved my issue/gave a solution to my question. He took al my concerns into account and it works like a charm.  -=-  Your example only set's a value to a base class prop in a sub class constructor.

Comment: @DavidG (Part 2)  This not answers the (single) question: `How to define the active property in the BaseJob which is false by default but in such a way i can "override" its default value in a child class` as its not `false` by default. Also the concern: `That I want to guarantee that the active propert can only be changed by using the related BaseJob functions as they may contain more logic than just toggle the "active" bool.` is not covered.